# How to use inheritance for calling and object from another class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, button, picturebox, mousehover

I am trying to call a button's visibility, from a MouseHover event on another object. 
What I'm trying to do is when I mouse over a pictureBox to set the button that is attached to that pictureBox to be visible, on default the button when it is created is invisible.
When I try to call it from the MouseHover event it says that the button is null. I'm not that good with inheritance so I'm kinda stuck here, any help would be appreciated.
Here is the code (what I'm trying to do is only on MouseHover event):

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel flP = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
    Label laB = new Label();
    Button btn = new Button();
    picB.Size = new Size(130, 70);
    laB.Size = new Size(130, 20);
    flP.Size = new Size(130, 90);
    btn.Size = new Size(20, 20);
    laB.Text = "Text";
    laB.Name = "Name";
    flP.Name = "Name";
    btn.Text = "X";
    btn.Name = "Name";
    btn.Visible = false;
    flP.Controls.Add(picB);
    flP.Controls.Add(laB);
    picB.Controls.Add(btn);
    flP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    laB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 70);
    btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 5);
    mainFLP.Controls.Add(flP);
    picB.MouseHover += picB_MouseHover;
    picB.DoubleClick += picB_DoubleClick;
}

private void picB_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    Button bt = pb.Parent as Button;
    //bt.Visible = true;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel flP = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
        Label laB = new Label();
        Button btn = new Button();
        picB.Size = new Size(130, 70);
        laB.Size = new Size(130, 20);
        flP.Size = new Size(130, 90);
        btn.Size = new Size(20, 20);
        flP.Name = i.ToString();
        laB.Name = "Link";
        laB.Text = "Name";
        btn.Text = "X";
        btn.Name = "b" + i.ToString();
        btn.Visible = false;
        flP.Controls.Add(picB);
        flP.Controls.Add(laB);
        picB.Controls.Add(btn);
        flP.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        laB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 70);
        btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 5);
        mainFLP.Controls.Add(flP);
        picB.MouseHover += picB_MouseHover;
        picB.DoubleClick += picB_DoubleClick;
    }
}

private void picB_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    FlowLayoutPanel flp = pb.Parent as FlowLayoutPanel;
    flp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note that inheritance does not play any role in this scenario

Comment: Ok but there has to be a way to make it visible without making the button global.

Comment: Button bt = (Button)pb.Controls[0];

Comment: Nice, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method can be to store the Button variable in tag property of your picture box:

```
PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
Button btn = new Button();
picB.Tag = btn;
```

and later, in your MouseHover Hanlder

```
private void picB_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
    Button bt = pb.Tag as Button;
    //bt.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: I see, so I can't directly call the button somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It is null because the sender of the event is the picture, not the button.
You can simply declare the button at the class level

```
private  Button btn;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel flP = new FlowLayoutPanel();
    PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
    Label laB = new Label();
    btn = new Button();
```

and then directly make it visible

```
private void picB_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bt.Visible = true;
}
```

**Edit**

Or you can define a Dictionary to associate the found PictureBox with the corresponding Button

```
private var btnDict = new Dictionary<PictureBox,Button>();
```

and when you create them, you can also link them,

```
PictureBox picB = new PictureBox();
Label laB = new Label();
Button btn = new Button();
btnDict.Add(picB,btn);
```

so that you can retrieve the button with a command like

```
PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
var btn = btnDict[pb];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am trying to access it like i did with the FlowLayoutPanel in DoubleClick event that is local in that class.

Comment: Or you can define a Dictionary to associate the found FlowLayoutPanel with the corresponding Button

Comment: The button is inside the PictureBox, the PictureBox is inside the FlowLayoutPanel. About that dictionary i don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show the pseudo-code for the Dictionary association between the Button and the Picture